# girth's meaning in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> He was lean, his ropey muscles giving his spare frame **girth**.

What does this girth mean in this context? A small figure?

Merriam Webster said: a measure around a body.

So I think it's a small figure, isn't it? If so, Why it's not girth spare frame but spare frame girth?

Thank you in advance!

What The Wind Knows, Amy Harmon.

Answer (score 1):

> He was lean, his ropey muscles giving his spare frame girth.

It means a larger figure than it would be without the ropey muscles. Here, the word "giving" means "adding".

The word "girth" is used to mean the "measure around", but here it means a larger girth.

The word works like "weight". To give weight to something is to make it heavier or more serious.